# php file_get_contents FTP

Tags: php, ftp, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get a file from a public ftp server via `file_get_contents`.

```
$url = 'ftp://ftp.server.de/my_file.txt';
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

I get the following error:

```
file_get_contents(): connect() failed: No route to host
```

`allow_url_fopen` is enabled.

What could be the problem?

Comment: beware of using file_get_contents with allow_url_fopen.
Use ftp related functions that PHP presents to you. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php

Comment: Is the FTP server fully functional? Try this `telnet ftp.server.de 21` to check. If this command returns an error then there is something wrong with the FTP server.

Comment: @1469 telnet works, but with wget I get the same error.

Comment: Is that your full script, or is there more? Connections etc?

Comment: @user2071225 The above is the full script.

Comment: What's the actual ftp url? If it's a public ftp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a firewall issue.

The PHP ftp wrapper uses only passive mode. So all ports have to be open.

Answer (score -1):

```
$url = 'www://ftp.server.de/my_file.txt';



$file = file_get_contents($url, true);
```

Try this

Comment: The include path has nothing to do with the ftp server